# Steps to migrate Core Data databases for shipped iPhone apps

Tags: iphone, core-data, data-migration

What are the recommended steps to be done for migrating Core Data DB changes for updated iPhone apps already shipped?

Is there any prior step one need (should) have done before shipping a Core Data app?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Apple has published a guide with regards to this topic:
[Introduction to Core Data Model Versioning and Data Migration Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Introduction/Introduction.html)

If you find the guide hard to follow (and it can be), this SO post may come in handy too:

[What do I have to do to get Core Data to automatically migrate models?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018155/what-do-i-have-to-do-to-get-core-data-to-automatically-migrate-models/1219911#1219911)

Comment: Super :) Why didn't I find that last SOQ in my search?...will send you some extra rep :)

Comment: That link to the Introduction to Core Data Model Versioning is not available anymore.

Comment: Try this: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/Introduction.html