# How to alter the structure of Core Data SQLite database without losing data

Tags: ios, sqlite, core-data

I have an app which uses core data, the database structure was designed through xCode.

I'm using a separate 3rd party app to populate the .SQLite file itself, and I'm wondering if there is a way to alter the structure of the database (and hence the managed object model) but not lose the data that is already in the .SQLite file?

I've run out of ideas on this one so any help appreciated.

Comment: What types of alterations in particular were you thinking of?

Comment: Initially just adding columns, possibly tables and relationships at a later stage!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Steps to migrate Core Data databases for shipped iPhone apps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262352/steps-to-migrate-core-data-databases-for-shipped-iphone-apps)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a semi-complex topic and is documented under the heading: Core Data Model Versioning and Data Migration.  Apple's guide is at: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/Introduction.html