# App crashes after updating it

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, core-data, app-store

I recently sended out an update of my app. Now I got some complaints from people who says that the app is always crashing. When I check it on the simulator and on device everything works properly.

Now my question is, has this something to do with my update.
Maybe this has something to do with my core database that I'm using or maybe something else?

Hope that anybody can tell me what the problem is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Impossible to answer.

Log in to iTunes Connect and download the Crash Reports. You might be able to find the answer there.

Comment: When I want to do that I get this. Too few reports have been submitted for a report to be shown.

Comment: Did you change anything in Core Data? In that case, have you migrated it?

Comment: Yes I added an ID to an entity. Maybe that was the problem. What do you mean by migrated it?

Comment: Have a look at this question/answer it might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262352/steps-to-migrate-core-data-databases-for-shipped-iphone-apps

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you manage your code properly then you should have a version handy which is exacly that what you sent to the store last time. Install that on your device. Run it. Then upgrade your own device and debug it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you performed an upgrade on your own devices?

Without knowing more from your crash reports this could be a `CoreData` migration issue (or lack of migration). If you changed your data model between versions you should have made sure a migration is performed (either automatically, or using a migration mapping).

If you did not do this the app will crash because of an managed object model vs. underlying database incompatibility error.

Read the [Core Data Model Versioning and Data Migration Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/Introduction.html) for more information on this.