# CoreData migration issue during attribute name changes

Tags: ios, iphone

I need to change my attribute name of entity in coredata ios. I want lightweight migration of it without crash. I have tried lot by referring migration tutorial  but app directly goes crash.

Comment: check this.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262352/steps-to-migrate-core-data-databases-for-shipped-iphone-apps

Comment: @Shruti do you have any demo that will be help me to understand well?

Answer (score 1):

Try Out with this link you can find demo here (http://www.raywenderlich.com/86136/lightweight-migrations-core-data-tutorial)

Comment: This is not working well. can u suggest something else for better meet to exactly what i am looking for.   Thank You

Answer (score 1):

Here is the list of step you have to follow.

[image: Step - 1]

[image: Step - 2]

After this make required changes into your new model(Example 2).

[image: Step - 3]

[image: Step - 4]

Select your current model version -

[image: Step - 5]

Comment: Good , but you haven't made the key point which is to how to map the old name of the property onto the new one. There is a possibility OP needs a mapping model in this case.

Comment: @Vijay Masiwal, thanks for your kind of interest, i have follow this all things but my exact issue is that how to map old attribute name with new name. Still application going to crash.

Comment: @Warren Burton Still i am looking for solution. Is there any possibility?