# Steps to migrate Realm databases for shipped iPhone apps

Tags: ios, objective-c, realm, data-migration

What are the steps for migrating Realm DB changes for updated iOS apps already shipped?

Is there any prior step one should have done before shipping a Realm.io database app?

Here are the similar question with respect to core-data
[Steps to migrate Core Data databases for shipped iPhone apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262352/steps-to-migrate-core-data-databases-for-shipped-iphone-apps), but I am looking for migrating Realm database.

**Here goes the crash logs:**

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Migration is required for object type 'ExampleRealm' due to the
>   following errors:
>   - Property 'values' has been added to latest object model.'

Comment: It probably depends on what your data store looks like now. Do you have your data in a Core Data store or in NSUserDefaults? Other than that, look at the Realm getting started guide. It's pretty good.

Comment: No core-data is been used. Since the app is still under development and while deploying the ad-hoc build with changes to realm database structure. App get crash unless we do a fresh install.

Comment: What sort of crash? Can you share a log in your original question?

Comment: yep, logs has been added.

Comment: Looks like you need to look up how to do a migration in Realm. Realm is complaining that one of your properties was added to the latest object model.

Comment: yeah that is what exactly I am looking for how to do a migration in Realm

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102184/discussion-between-shaf-khan-and-moshe).

Answer (score 3):

According to [the Realm documentation](https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/#models), there are some samples of how you do a migration in Realm.

From the sample code, there's this:

```
// define a migration block
// you can define this inline, but we will reuse this to migrate realm files from multiple versions
// to the most current version of our data model
RLMMigrationBlock migrationBlock = ^(RLMMigration *migration, uint64_t oldSchemaVersion) {
    if (oldSchemaVersion < 1) {
        [migration enumerateObjects:Person.className block:^(RLMObject *oldObject, RLMObject *newObject) {
            if (oldSchemaVersion < 1) {
                // combine name fields into a single field
                newObject[@"fullName"] = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", oldObject[@"firstName"], oldObject[@"lastName"]];
            }
        }];
    }
    if (oldSchemaVersion < 2) {
        [migration enumerateObjects:Person.className block:^(RLMObject *oldObject, RLMObject *newObject) {
            // give JP a dog
            if ([newObject[@"fullName"] isEqualToString:@"JP McDonald"]) {
                Pet *jpsDog = [[Pet alloc] initWithValue:@[@"Jimbo", @(AnimalTypeDog)]];
                [newObject[@"pets"] addObject:jpsDog];
            }
        }];
    }
    if (oldSchemaVersion < 3) {
        [migration enumerateObjects:Pet.className block:^(RLMObject *oldObject, RLMObject *newObject) {
            // convert type string to type enum if we have outdated Pet object
            if (oldObject && oldObject.objectSchema[@"type"].type == RLMPropertyTypeString) {
                newObject[@"type"] = @([Pet animalTypeForString:oldObject[@"type"]]);
            }
        }];
    }
    NSLog(@"Migration complete.");
```

It looks like you declare a block in which you enumerate objects and manually update the schema.