# Replacing Core Data SQLite file in app

Tags: iphone, sqlite, core-data

I'm creating an SQLite file on the Mac using Core Data and then placing it in my iPhone app ([GitHub project](http://github.com/baalexander/Geography-Importer) if curious). I want to release an update to the app with with an updated SQLite file. The model will be the same entities and attributes, there will just be more data.

I run the app in simulator with the old sqlite file. Exit. Replace the sqlite file with the new one in xcode. Add NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption and NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption to the addPeristentStore options. Then run the app again, but the app only shows the same data from the original file.

I've also tried versioning the model as per the Apple docs and this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018155/what-do-i-have-to-do-to-get-core-data-to-automatically-migrate-models) and renaming the sqlite file. But still no luck (I'm guessing because the model is still the same?).

Any ideas on how I can have the app read the newer sqlite file?

Answer (score 3):

My Core Data iPhone app uses the standard code provided when the project is created and "Use Core Data for storage" is selected.
It will switch the SQLite database that is used when I change the value of my filename constant "DB_NAME" and rebuild:

```
NSURL *storeUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] stringByAppendingPathComponent:DB_NAME]];

NSError *error = nil;
persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];
if (![persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeUrl options:nil error:&error]) {
```