# modyfing a sqlite db mapped via core data throws errors: uncaught exception of class 'NSCFString'

Tags: cocoa, core-data, ios4, sqlite

I have an iphone app that has a sqlite db, mapped to core data. All the data manipulation in the app is via Coredata.

On one table I wanted to add a string attribute. And I did two things both with similar crashes:

1. I tried to use Mesasql to alter the structure. I easily added a Varchar column. But it crashes.
2. On a separate attempt, with the mapped SQLlite db, restored, I tried adding a attribute to the entity in core data and it crashed.

This is the error I got:
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception of class 'NSCFString'
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSCFString'

So, how can I alter the structure of the sqlite table mapped to core data without breaking the app? Am I fogetting to do a commit or something like that?

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you modify an entity you have to delete the sqlite store. If your application has already shipped, the alternative is to [migrate your data](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Introduction/Introduction.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004399). This [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018155/what-do-i-have-to-do-to-get-core-data-to-automatically-migrate-models/1018384#1018384) offers a simple explanation of how to do that.

Comment: so i have to delete the sqllite db and Xcode will recreate it?

Comment: Yes, it will be recreated when you launch the app again.

Comment: ok, I created a migration directory and then created a migration named.1. I modified the data model and entity classes to reflect the two new attributes. I deleted the sqllite DB within xcode (it had asked me if I only wanted to erase the references). I then re-ran, and super crash, plus it does not recreate the sqlite DB. Ideas of what might be happening?

Comment: The Core Data schema for SQLite is undocumented. If you edit the file directly, there is an excellent chance you will corrupt it. Delete the file and start over.

Comment: TechZen, delete the SQLite DB or the core data model file?

Comment: Definitely the SQLite DB. I think it should be located here: `~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/User/Applications/<your app id>/Documents/<appname>.sqlite`. Also, can you post the crash log?

Comment: I delete both the one in the app directory in my map and on the iphone and nothing works. I think the app is missing the core data creation functions.....

Comment: can you post your appdelegate code, i.e. any core data relevant code?