# Migrating Core Data - how to do it safely?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data, core-data-migration

I have an app released, and I want to release a new version.

The new version has a very small change in the Core Data model: adding a BOOL attribute ("hasUpdated") to an entity ("Users").

How would I migrate without the app crashing after being updated (obviously) or changing the existing data?

Answer (score 3):

First, make sure the data model you are using (with the new BOOL attribute) is a different version than the one that you have released. To create a new model I believe it's something like Editor -> Add Model Version -> and then name it / tell it which model to be based from.

Now set the new model as the current version in the utility pane. For help on this check out this post: [Xcode 4, Core Data Model Version - Set Current Version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5372479/xcode-4-core-data-model-version-set-current-version)

For such a simple change you should be able to tell the persistent store to perform lightweight migration. This post should explain that: [Implementation of "Automatic Lightweight Migration" for Core Data (iPhone)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2310216/implementation-of-automatic-lightweight-migration-for-core-data-iphone)