# Core Data versioning still loading old mom file

Tags: ios, core-data, model, versioning

I have problem with versioning Core Data. I added a new entity Event and followed all the steps for versioning. I have a folder Model.momd containing Model.mom, Model2.mom and Model2.omo and the version file. I have changed loading modelObjectContext to loading from momd folder.

- **When I load app to my iPhone using Xcode it works.** However, when
- **I create an archive and replace the Appstore version** with this new version through iTunes **I get the  error message below**.
  Thanks

  createUnresolved error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134130 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 134130.)" UserInfo=0x20147820 {URL=file://localhost/var/mobile/Applications/3B2BD803-401D-4A95-ACDA-DD6A7D197930/Documents/Database.sqlite, metadata={
      NSPersistenceFrameworkVersion = 419;
      NSStoreModelVersionHashes = {
          State = <0bfe87fd 1e1b5822 eb704808 86efd0ca 61c108c3 328c095d 2f2eadb8 4c51a17f>;
      };
      NSStoreModelVersionHashesVersion = 3;
      NSStoreModelVersionIdentifiers =     (
          ""
      );
      NSStoreType = SQLite;
      NSStoreUUID = "C2EDD217-1F20-425A-927E-1B9A1C661085";
      "_NSAutoVacuumLevel" = 2;
  }, reason=Can't find model for source store.

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8641802/core-data-migration-xcode-4-2-is-not-update-the-data-for-app-already-available-i/8641836#8641836

Comment: I try every think what I found on websites. All files are generated fine but old mom file is still loaded. I there some way how say ios load right this file Model2.mom?

Comment: how did you solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have database model in folder in project even in folder on HDD. When I move database model to root of xcode project versioning start working.

Answer (score 0):

Have you chosen the current model in the File Inspector?

[image: Version setting]

Your core data model when in the Project Navigator should look something like this

[image: Project Navigator]

Comment: Yes I have selected version 2.